# Split Wordpress megamenu submenu into two columns

Tags: css, wordpress, multiple-columns, megamenu

I created a megamenu in Wordpress by adding the class mega-menu. Simple enough.  My first submenu has 18 items which appear in a single column.  I'd like to split this column into 2 columns.  I applied the class sub-menu-columns to the submenu top-item and tried the following code but it didn't change anything.  Any suggestions?

```
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li {
display: inline-block;
float: left;
width:200px;
}

.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(odd) {
    float: left;
    margin-right: 10px;
}

.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li:nth-child(even) {
    float: right;
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try flex?

```
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu{display:flex} 
.sub-menu-columns ul.sub-menu li{flex: 0 50%}
```

More info can be found here to fine tuning.
[CSS flexbox](http://%20https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)